# Reverse display in a pie chart in obiee

Tags: oracle, obiee, oracle-bi

I have a problem in OBIEE, I create pie chart but it dosen't show correctly.
I write this measure :
case  when "n_dim_city_senderDim"."sendercityname"='تهران' then '1'  when "n_dim_city_senderDim"."PROVINCENAME" IN ('البرز', 'تهران') then '2' end

but 2 should bigger than 1. It shows inverse
How can I correct?!

I threw the measure in different places but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this

```
case when "n_dim_city_senderDim"."sendercityname" ='تهران'           then '1' 
     when "n_dim_city_senderDim"."PROVINCENAME"  IN ('البرز', 'تهران') then '2' 
end
```

returns `1`, while you expect it to return `2`. That's because there are rows that contain both `province_name` as well `sendercityname` equal to / are contained in values you specified.

If `provincename` should take precedence, switch conditions to

```
case when "n_dim_city_senderDim"."PROVINCENAME"  IN ('البرز', 'تهران') then '1' 
     when "n_dim_city_senderDim"."sendercityname" ='تهران'           then '2' 
end
```

---

**[EDIT]** To illustrate it:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by 1;

SENDERCITYNAME  PROVINCENAME
--------------- ---------------
Montreal        Quebec
Winnipeg        Manitoba
```

First query:

```
SQL> select
  2    sendercityname,
  3    provincename,
  4    case when sendercityname = 'Montreal'            then 1
  5         when provincename in ('Quebec', 'Manitoba') then 2
  6    end as result
  7  from test
  8  order by 1;

SENDERCITYNAME  PROVINCENAME        RESULT
--------------- --------------- ----------
Montreal        Quebec                   1
Winnipeg        Manitoba                 2
```

Second query, whose `CASE` expressions are **opposite** from the 1st query:

```
SQL> select
  2    sendercityname,
  3    provincename,
  4    case when provincename in ('Quebec', 'Manitoba') then 1
  5         when sendercityname = 'Montreal'            then 2
  6    end as result
  7  from test
  8  order by 1;

SENDERCITYNAME  PROVINCENAME        RESULT
--------------- --------------- ----------
Montreal        Quebec                   1
Winnipeg        Manitoba                 1

SQL>
```

See the difference?

Comment: Do you mean that priority is important?

Comment: Yes, if I understood the problem right. I edited the answer and added example which shows what I meant to say.